# How to make Little Snitch only block the upload traffic, but not the download traffic？

Tags: macos, catalina, firewall

I didn't find a way to do that, please help!

Comment: Have you [contacted Objective Development](https://www.obdev.at/support/index.html?product=LS), the developers of Little Snitch, for help? What did they say?

Comment: @GrahamMiln I don't think the question is off-topic. It's more like a combination of an xy-problem and missing knowledge how TCP/IP (and 2nd or 3rd gen firewalls) work.

Comment: It would be good to know what Little Snitch's developer's advise. Ask Different should not replace a commercial product's customer support. If Objective Development do not or can not help, then the question has further merit.

Comment: Can you please add some details on what you've tried so far, and what specific traffic you want to block?

Answer (score 1):

Both uploads and downloads consists of data packets going both in and out of your computer. Therefore you cannot block only one direction and still have a working data transfer.

In rough terms a download works by your computer sending a data packet to the server letting it know you want to download such and such a file. The server will reply with a small part of the data, whereafter it expects your computer to acknowledge that it received that data. If it does not receive the acknowledgement, it assumes the data was lost and tries retransmitting, eventually considering the connection broken.

Little Snitch works (by default) by blocking new connections that are initiated by programs on your computer (i.e. a new connection is when the first data packet is sent from your computer to the remote server). You will be prompted the first time, so that you can allow similar connections in the future. Even though the connection is initiated locally, it can be be either an upload or a download or a mix of both - you cannot determine that by looking only at the first packet sent.

Newer versions of Little Snitch similarly control incoming connections to your computer. Here you'll get the advance prompt only for TCP connections, whereas UDP connections will just be blocked by default, allowing you to remove the block later (for future packets only). Incoming connection filtering like this is not that commonly used, compared to the traditional workings of Little Snitch described above, which is very popular amongst Mac users.

Comment: One has to add that LittleSnitch already works like this: incoming traffic from a connection initiated by the host isn't blocked. Only incoming traffic initiated by the remote host (e.g. trying to access a httpd or a DNS server on the local host) can be blocked (more or less Stateful Packet Inspection).

Comment: @klanomath No, LittleSnitch definitely does not work that way.

Comment: @klanomath Ah, I think I know what you're trying to say now. What you're describing is simply a dynamic packet filter - which is not entirely what Little Snitch is about.

Comment: I.e. so you mean that incoming traffic is blocked, unless that incoming traffic happens to match an earlier connection initiated by the local host. This is not really the use case for Little Snitch - that's just ordinary dynamic packet filtering.

Comment: I know, but you cannot have an "connection initiated by the host" unless you had previous outgoing traffic.

Comment: "Stateful packet inspection ('SPI), also referred to as dynamic packet filtering...": [Stateful firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateful_firewall)

Comment: On Mobile so short answer. When you say “packet inspection” it means that the firewall looks into the payload of the packet to determine whether or not to forward it. This is not how Little Snitch commonly works. It works like most other firewalls by looking at the header information, such as source and destination IP and port numbers - Little Snitch expands on the traditional firewall by looking at metadata such as which program originated the packet, what the code signature on that program says, etc. It doesn’t look at the packet payload to determine this.

Comment: Your comment was worded so that it could be misunderstood, but it is mostly correct. You’re just missing those incoming packets that come from a remote host that are due to something initiated on the local computer - they can be blocked as well. In addition this is done without inspecting the payload of the packet. So almost correct. However you’re missing the most important way that Little Snitch works - namely by blocking outgoing packets on connections initiated the local computer. So it cannot only block packets coming from remote, but rather function primarily by blocking packets (...)

Comment: (...) sent locally.

Comment: In addition to that, there’s the whole functionality of Little Snitch regarding connectionless tragic - which can also be filtered (and is by default). All together this means that “ Only incoming traffic initiated by the remote host (...) can be blocked (...)” is not entirely correct.

Comment: To further illustrate - most home users are behind NAT. This in itself provides what you call SPI, or I denote dynamic packet filtering. If this was the only functionality of Little Snitch, it wouldn’t have been as popular as it is. If Little Snitch didn’t have this feature, it would still be hugely useful to users behind NAT.